# Google cloud app engine Re Enable functionality not working

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

We had set up node application 
due to some reason it was disabled.
Now we want to enable it by using setting page in app engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW6oz.png)

but problem is when we click on Enable application.

It says app is starting... but again get into disable state without giving any error.

Kindly help if i'm missing anything

Comment: I got the same error. Did you get through it ?

Comment: Nope i have reported this issue you but no solutions until now https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68358438

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I also encountered. There is no Support from Google this is unfortunate. To solve this issue, I detroyed the application.

Then I entered a 30 days grace period, I thus clicked on the restore link from the email I automatically received from Google and I could restore my app.

Then, simply redeploy and you will manage to fully recover.

```
gcloud app deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

The [reported issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68358438) has been linked to [issue 68331967](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68331967) which has been [reported as fixed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68331967#comment6):

> kh...@google.com  #6 Oct 31, 2017 04:08PM This
>   issue should be fixed by now. Please try enabling your project and let
>   me know if you need further assistance.

And the fix was [confirmed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68331967#comment7) by the submitter:

> ja...@gmail.com  #7 Nov 1, 2017 11:53AM Great, seems
>   to work. Thank you!

You may want to give it a try as well.

Comment: Nope this was working for  issue 68331967 but not for me